# Use stored value to call or create & call sheet

Tags: excel, worksheet, vba

I have a workbook that creates other workbooks and shifts data to them based on the value in column one. Afterwords I need the workbook to store the data it has just copied in a sheet of the same name as the stored variable (in the next empty row), or create the tab if it does not exist.

However i'm having an issue pasting into the tab with the name of the variable, and no idea how to create a new sheet if the variable does not already exist as a sheet.

It's the `With Worksheets(SupID).Range("A" & LastRow(SupID) + 1).Paste` i'm having trouble with.

Current code below. Thanks!

```
Private Sub CopyItOver()

 Dim myVal As String
 Dim SupID As String

    'Store Supplier ID
  SupID = Trim(Sheets("Raw Data").Range("A2").Value)

    'Create workbook
  Set newbook = Workbooks.Add

    'Copy Records
  Set myRng = Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("B2:X7")
  myRng.Copy
  newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

    'Create Header
  newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "ZHF"
  newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value = "CTO"
  newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Value = "RET"
  newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1").Value = SupID
  newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").Value = "RET"
  newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F1").Value = "RET"
  newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G1").Value = "6"
  newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H1").Value = "PROD"
    newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J1").Value =     newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value _
    & newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1").Value & "TEMPNUMBER"
  newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I1").Value =     newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J1").Value _
    & newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Value & ".CSV"
 newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K1") = Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy")
 newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L1").Value = "Unknown"
 newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("M1").Value = "1"

LastRow = newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'Create Footer
  newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & LastRow + 1).Value = "ZFV"
  newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & LastRow + 1).Value = "BATCH" & "TEMPNUMBER"
  newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & LastRow + 1).Value =     WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A1000"), "RET")

    'Name Sheet
  myVal = newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J1").Value & "RET"
  newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Name = myVal

    'Copy to relevant matching sheet
    With Worksheets(SupID).Range("A" & LastRow(SupID) + 1).Paste
    End With

    'Save Workbook
  NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=NewBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I1").Value

End Sub
Function DLastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve my issue using help from [Here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/537711-visual-basic-applications-create-worksheet-if-doesnt-exist.html), to which I adapted to the code below and ran in a separate module, which allows for the use of a previously unspecified sheet name, that is later derived from a cell value. If the sheet does not exist, it is created matching the name to the stored value and the data pasted into it. Thanks for the support!

```
Sub TEST()

    Dim i As Integer, blnFound As Boolean
    blnFound = False

    SupID = Trim(Sheets("Raw Data").Range("A2").Value)
    Set myRng = Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("B2:X7")

    myRng.Copy

    With ThisWorkbook
        For i = 1 To .Sheets.Count
            If .Sheets(i).Name = SupID Then
            blnFound = True
            .Sheets(i).Activate
            ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Range("A" & LastRow + 1)
            Exit For
            End If
        Next i

        If blnFound = False Then
        .Sheets.Add
        With ActiveSheet
            .Name = SupID

            ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Range("A" & LastRow + 1)
        End With
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The error's occurring because `Worksheets(SupID).Range("A" & LastRow(SupID) + 1).Paste` is trying to find that worksheet on your active book, ie the new book. You'd need either to `Activate` your raw data workbook or change the line to `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SupID).Range("A" & LastRow(SupID) + 1).Paste`.

However, it's not great to use (either explicitly or implicitly) `Activate`, `Select` or other keystroke style commands in VBA. Given that you're only copying values (and not the worksheet formats) then, you'd probably be better served reading the data into an array of variants and manipulating those. I've adjusted your code to demonstrate this.

There are some other coding aspects that might not be as robust as they could be. I won't list them all but a comparison of this code with yours will help you see them.

```
Private Sub CopyItOver()
    Dim newBook As Workbook
    Dim supSheet As Worksheet
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim supID As String
    Dim namePrefix As String
    Dim footerCount As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    'Store Supplier ID
    supID = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A2").value)
    namePrefix = "CTO" & supID & "TEMPNUMBER"

    'Create workbook
    Set newBook = Workbooks.Add

    'Copy Records
    v = rawDataSheet.Range("B2:X7").value
    For i = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
        If v(i, 1) = "RET" Then footerCount = footerCount + 1
    Next

    'Write new sheet
    With newBook.Worksheets(1)
        'Values
        .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(v, 1), UBound(v, 2)).value = v
        'Header
        .Range("A1").Resize(, 13) = Array( _
            "ZHF", "CTO", "RET", supID, "RET", "RET", "6", "PROD", _
            namePrefix & "RET.CSV", namePrefix, _
            Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy"), "Unknown", "1")
        'Footer
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(, 3).value = Array( _
            "ZFV", "BATCH TEMPNUMBER", footerCount)
        'Name
        .Name = namePrefix & "RET"
        'Save
        .SaveAs Filename:=namePrefix & "RET.CSV"
    End With

    'Copy to relevant matching sheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set supSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(supID)
    On Error Goto 0
    If newSheet Is Nothing Then
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            Set supSheet = .Add(After:=.Item(.Count))
        End With
        supSheet.Name = supID
    End If

    With supSheet
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(UBound(v, 1), UBound(v, 2)).value = v
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks @Ambie. Shows i've still got a long way in my coding journey. Really useful to compare this to mine to see the differences. I will take on board your comment on using arrays rather than the direct copying i'm doing. Both solved my problem and gave a better/more efficient/robust solution. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: May I request one amendment, which I have attempted but cannot amend myself. The line `.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Resize(, 3).value = Array( _
            "ZFV", "BATCH TEMPNUMBER", footerCount)` overwrites current data in that row. Is there a way to make it look at the next row? I tried to add 1 to the row but I couldn't get it to work. Thanks.

Comment: Ignore me, I resolved it copying your `.offset(1)` from the coding below the line.

Comment: You're welcome. Your code was fine ... and all of our coding journeys have a long way to go!! I also forgot actually to answer your question about how to check for and add a woksheet, so I've edited my code to include that and the correction you have made (good spot, thanks).

Answer (score 1):

A few things that aren't quite right:

- Add `Option Explicit` at the top of the module and declare your variables.
- `LastRow` will be a `Long` data type, but you're trying to use it like an array in `With Worksheets(SupID).Range("A" & LastRow(SupID) + 1).Paste`.  Just use `LastRow+1`.
- `With Worksheets(SupID).Range("A" & LastRow(SupID) + 1).Paste
  End With` should probably be `Worksheets(SupID).Range("A" & LastRow + 1).Paste`, but it will paste `myRng` - can't see anything else you've copied.
- At the start of the code you reference `Workbooks("Book1.xlsm")`.  If this is the workbook that the code is in I'd change it to `ThisWorkbook`.
- `SupID` looks at Raw Data on whichever workbook is active at the time (you'd don't specify the workbook when initialising that variable).

This function will return TRUE/FALSE if a named worksheet exists:

```
Public Function WorkSheetExists(SheetName As String) As Boolean
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
        Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName)
        WorkSheetExists = (Err.Number = 0)
        Set wrkSht = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Hope that points you in the right direction :)

**Edit:**
Just noticed to....

Rather than write:

```
  newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "ZHF"
  newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value = "CTO"
  newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Value = "RET"
  newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1").Value = SupID
  newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").Value = "RET"
  newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F1").Value = "RET"
  newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G1").Value = "6"
  newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H1").Value = "PROD"
```

You can just use:

```
newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:H1") = Array("ZHF", "CTO", "RET", "SupID", "RET", "RET", "6", "Prod")
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your comments. Yeah I do need to tidy this up a bit. It is cobbled together from myself and a few bits of other code I found. I managed to adapt the code from [link](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/537711-visual-basic-applications-create-worksheet-if-doesnt-exist.html) which allows for the pasting into, or creation and then pasting into of a sheet name that matches the stored variable (from the previous sheet).